# Using coefficient estimates and standard errors to assess significance

Tags: statistical-significance

Gelman & Hill 2007 mention several times throughout their book that:

"Roughly speaking, if a coefficient estimate is more than 2 standard errors away from zero, then it is called statistically significant. "

However, when they use this rule throughout this book I find the conclusions inconsistent. For example from the ouput:

```
(formula = kid.score ~ mom.hs + mom.iq) coef.est coef.se
(Intercept) 25.7 5.9
mom.hs 5.9 2.2
mom.iq 0.6 0.1
n = 434, k = 3
residual sd = 18.1, R-Squared = 0.21
```

They conclude that mom.hs is statistically significant with an estimate of 5.9 and an a standard error of 2.2

Then in a second output:

```
lm(formula = log.earn ~ height + male) coef.est coef.se

(Intercept) 8.153 0.603
height 0.021 0.009
male 0.423 0.072

n = 1192, k = 3
residual sd = 0.88, R-Squared = 0.09
```

they say that height is statistically significant with an estimate of 0.021 and a standard error of 0.009

then in a third example:

```
lm(formula = log(weight) ~ log(canopy.volume) + log(canopy.area) + log(canopy.shape) + log(total.height) + log(density) + group)

coef.est coef.se 
(Intercept) 5.35 0.17 
log(canopy.volume) 0.37 0.28 
log(canopy.area) 0.40 0.29 
log(canopy.shape) -0.38 0.23 
log(total.height) 0.39 0.31 
log(density) 0.11 0.12 
group -0.58 0.13
n = 46, k = 7
residual sd = 0.33, R-Squared = 0.89
```

they say that none of the variables are significant even though to me they seem to have even higher values than the other examples.

What am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For each of the examples, you can easily perform `abs(estimate) - 2 * standarderror`. If this is higher than zero (i.e. the estimate is more than two standard errors away from zero), it is very unlikely that the true value is zero, i.e. it is statistically significantly nonzero (at nearly the 95% confidence level).

This is the case for the first two examples (e.g. `5.9 - 2* 2.2 > 0`)

If the difference is smaller than zero, we cannot say with enough confidence that the true value is nonzero. Thus it is *not* statistically significantly nonzero.

This is the case, I believe, for all the coefficients in the last example.

All in all, it seems the statements are consistent with the examples, no?

Comment: yes, by inconsistent I wasn't referring to the statements only my personal opinion without knowing how to interpret them. THank you for the clear answer.